# How does the compiler call a Derived member function, when I use a member function pointer defined in terms of the Base class?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

The code below works, but I'm not quite sure I understand why the member function pointer `memfunc_ptr` ends up pointing to the correct function `Derived::member_func()` (see example [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d620a5de7eecf854)). I know that a member function pointer defines an **offset** into the class of the object, for which it's defined, in this case class `Base`. So, to justify the result obtained by the code, i.e., that the member function `Derived::member_func` is called, instead of `Base::member_func`, I have to conclude that this **offset** is applied to the vtable of the class `Derived`, as `member_func()` is virtual, and the object `d` is of class `Derived`. Does that make sense?

```
#include <iostream>
class Base {
public: 
    virtual void member_func() {
    std::cout << "Base" << '\n'; };
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    virtual void member_func() { std::cout << "Derived" << '\n'; };
};

int main() {
    typedef void (Base::*MFP)();
    MFP memfunc_ptr;
    memfunc_ptr = &Base::member_func;
    Derived d;
    (d.*memfunc_ptr)(); 
}
```

Comment: ["Virtual Method Table"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table)

Comment: Yes it's often implemented as the offset into a vtable, see e.g. http://mentorembedded.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#member-pointers

Comment: @n.m. That seems to be an answer to my question. Would you care to provide an answer, so that I can close this thread?

Answer (score 3):

`member_func()` is a virtual function.  The compiler will hence always call the most appropriate function for the real type of the object that is pointed to.  The way this is ensured is **implementation specific**.

The most frequently way to do it is to use a [vtable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table), a table of funtion pointers.  A pointer to the vtable is initialised during the construction of the object.  Every time you refer to such a virtual function, the compiler will generate code to find the function pointer in the vtable (using an ofset in the vtable).  And when you use a pointer to a virtual function, the compiler will generate code to find the right pointer in the vtable.

This [article](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/125-the-virtual-table/) will show you how this work with more details.